# Javascript image plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Complete javascript newbie here. I am trying to use the [medium-editor-insert-plugin](https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin#usage) to insert images into my text but have no clue what i'm doing.

My comments form looks like this (I dumped all the scripts at the top):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="medium-editor/css/medium-editor.css">
<script src="medium-editor/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="medium-editor-insert-plugin/css/medium-editor-insert-plugin.css">
<script src="medium-editor-insert-plugin/js/medium-editor-insert-plugin.all.min.js"></script>

<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>

<%= f.input :body %>

<% end %>
```

and my comments.js.coffee looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $(".editable").mediumInsert
    editor: editor
    images: true
```

No error is given but nothing happens.

Comment: So, indentation is actually very important in CoffeeScript, and you're kind of winging it. It matters [**this much**](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24%20-%3E%0A%20%24(%22.editable%22).mediumInsert%0A%20%20editor%3A%20editor%0A%20%20%20images%3A%20true%0A%0A%24%20-%3E%0A%20%24(%22.editable%22).mediumInsert%0A%20%20%20editor%3A%20edito%0A%20%20%20images%3A%20true); your version is almost certain to produce an error about a missing `editor` function.

Comment: No i don't think its that; i copy and pasted from js2coffee and used their spacing.

Comment: I'm telling you that the code you've posted in the question is wrong, so do with that information what you will.

Comment: Oh my bad i didn't notice the code i'm using and the posted code are different. I'll post the revised.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ ->
  var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');
  $(".editable").mediumInsert
    editor: editor
    images: true
```

Comment: How about adding `<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>` just below medium editor script? (and of course discarding answer above)

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's a little old question, but did you solve the problem?

First of all, I don't see any element with `editable` class. Maybe `<%= f.input :body %>` produces input/textarea with `editable` class, but the second thing is, that MediumEditor should be attached to block (`div`) element, not input/textarea.